# add left and right bars to joomla article

Tags: joomla

I'm not very familiar with joomla, I added new article , But the left and right positions (right & left bars) don't appear in the two sides, How to add them please?

Thank you

Comment: The website I'm working on has already a position right and left added by a joomla developer...I just don't know how to add them to the article

Comment: check jdoc modules included at your index.php page

Comment: can't understand about two side?? can you be more specific about your question??

Comment: @Jogesh_p, Of course , I mean the sidebars that appear in the home page, I want to insert them in an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Module Manager, then select the modules you want to show, ensure they are enabled on all pages. I wouldn't have though you have to create html page using the article manager. Joomla isnt really built for this. Regards

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, then i think you want to add two columns in your article page.

There is a simplest want in you article editor click on the `html` button which show you a new window where you can set your html. And for two side that is left and right, just create a html page and paste in only the body content into your joomla editor and if you want to add some style then define id's or class's to your article or you can set inline css..

hope this will help you..